# How to catch JSON object when server and client on the same system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I made HTML page that have form, when submitting, it calls JavaScript by using this event handler.

```
 onClick = operation(this.form)
```

and **the JavaScript is:**

```
function operation(x) {
    //url:"C:\Users\jhamb\Desktop\assignment_1_18_1_13\question_3\ques\form1.html",
    url:"http://localhost:8080",
    $.ajax({
       data:{
           comment:x.comment.value,       // information from html page
           email: x.email.value,          // information from html page
           url:x.url.value,               // information from html page
           name:x.name.value,             // information from html page
       }
    }).done(function(serverResponse){
         alert("response is ready");    //here you can handle server response
    }).fail(function(err){
         alert("ohhh!!! there is some error");   //here you can handle errors
    });

    //alert(obj.details[3].comment_value);
}
```

Now what I want is to communicate between server and client , that is on same system.
My code is not working. Now what can I do, please help.

Comment: Have you set up a web server in your host and is it listening in the port 8080?

Comment: Could be a typo but is it hitting the method as I notice your onClick = opeation(this.form). is missing an "r"

Comment: Till now I wrote only these codes. I don't know anything beyond that.(Since I am new in this technology)

Comment: Recheck the name of your function like @CR41G14 said, may be this is the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i don't think your server listens on port 8080, that normaly aport for the admin software.

second you have to put the url inside the ajax request

```
function operation(x) {
    //url:"C:\Users\jhamb\Desktop\assignment_1_18_1_13\question_3\ques\form1.html",

    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080",
        data:{
            comment:x.comment.value,       // information from html page
            email: x.email.value,          // information from html page
            url:x.url.value,               // information from html page
            name:x.name.value,             // information from html page
        }
    }).done(function(serverResponse){
        alert("response is ready");    //here you can handle server response
    }).fail(function(err){
        alert("ohhh!!! there is some error");   //here you can handle errors
    });

//alert(obj.details[3].comment_value);
}
```

you shoul also add `dataType` (html or json), the sending `type` (post, get etc.) in the param list

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help if you modify tour code slightly:

```
function operation(x) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080",
        data: $(x).serialize(),
    }).done(function (serverResponse) {
        alert("response is ready");
    }).fail(function (err) {
        alert("ohhh!!! there is some error");
    });
}
```